# how to load class file from bin to JETTY server

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty-9

How to load class files from eclipse(bin folder) to jetty (webapps/WEB-INF/classes) folder automatically after every change?

Comment: How do you build your code? Do you use maven?

Comment: No, I use java project. Every time when I make changes to the local file, I have to manually copy the files to webapps folder and restart the jetty server.

Comment: I'd recommend using maven with for example this plugin: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try it out. :-)